# Criar uma expressão regular para validar pelo menos três caracteres(aceitando espaços)

Tags: html5, regex

Estou usando esse no meu código :

```
<input
    required
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3, }"
    title="Por favor, preencha pelo menos 3 caracteres entre letras e números."
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="pesquisa"
    name="q"
    placeholder="Buscar ..."
>
```

Comment: Tente assim `.{3,}`

Comment: não funciona o regex deve aceitar espaços em branco

Comment: o ponto aceita qualquer caractere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira que o @sam apresentou funciona:

```html
<form name="ExpressaoRegular">
   Por favor, preencha pelo menos 3 caracteres entre letras e números.
   <input type="text" name="teste"
      pattern=".{3,}">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> A não ser que haja múltiplas linhas (multiline), então você pode
>   utilizar `[/s/S]{3,}`

E se não quiser incluir caracteres especiais e somente espaço, letras e números:

```html
<form name="ExpressaoRegular">
   Por favor, preencha pelo menos 3 caracteres entre letras e números.
   <input type="text" name="teste"
      pattern="[\w\d\s]{3,}">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: funcionou! obrigado.